# Prove that $(A \triangle C) \cap (B \triangle C) \subseteq (A \cap B) \triangle C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is a exercise from How To Prove It by Velleman.  Exercise 3.5.24 to be exact.  The solutions I can find online involve using 4 cases.  My proof involves 2 so I was wondering if I was skipping some steps.

Proof: Let x be an arbitrary element of $(A \triangle C) \cap (B \triangle C)$.  It follows that $x \in A \triangle C$ and $x \in B \triangle C$.

We will consider 2 cases.

Case 1: $x \in C$.  Since $x \in A \triangle C$, it follows that $x \notin A$.  Also since $x \in B \triangle C$, it follows that $x \notin B$.  This means $x \in C \setminus (A \cap B)$ thus $x \in (A \cap B) \triangle C$.

Case 2: $x \notin C$.  Since $x \in A \triangle C$, it follows that $x \in A$.  Also since $x \in B \triangle C$, it follows that $x \in B$.  This means $x \in (A \cap B) \setminus C$ thus $x \in (A \cap B) \triangle C$.

Both cases gave us $x \in (A \cap B) \triangle C$ and since x was arbitrary $(A \triangle C) \cap (B \triangle C)  \subseteq (A \cap B) \triangle C$

Is this proof a valid one?  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good to me...

Comment: The proof is fine but in Case 1 the second sentence is not necessary.