# Prove that $ (A \triangle B) \cap (A \triangle C) \subseteq A \triangle (B \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$ (A \triangle B) \cap (A \triangle C) \subseteq A \triangle (B \cap C)$
I need to prove this result but I'm all out of ideas on how to go about it. I tried using both definitions of the symmetric difference: $A \triangle B = (A \cup B)- (A \cap B)$ and also $A \triangle B = (A - B) \cup (B - A)$. I've tried element chasing with these definitions and to no avail. I would greatly appreciate any clues or hints to guide me in the  right direction. Thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3090460/104041).

Comment: Can you state how you tried element chasing?

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried letting $x  \in (A  \triangle B) \cap (A \triangle C)$ then $x$ must be in both, $x \in (A-B) \cup (B-A)$ and $x \in (A-C) \cup (C-A)$. From there I tried to use the distributive property of the and with respect to the or but that didn't lead me anywhere useful. I tried a bunch of stuff here and there but never could come up with $x \in A \triangle (B \cap C)$

Comment: That's a good approach, So with the distributive property you have 4 cases, based on whether $ x \in A-B$ or $B-A$ and $ x \in A-C $ or $C - A$. Can you consider those cases? EG What can we say if $ x \in A-B$ and $C-A$? What about if $ x \in B-A$ and $C - A$?

Comment: @CalvinLin The idea of dividing it by cases was pretty useful, I was able to prove it using only two cases, similar to what the link posted above.

Answer (score 1):

By distributivity,
$(A\ \bigoplus B\cap A\ \bigoplus C)=(A\backslash B \cup B \backslash A)\cap(A \backslash C \cup C\backslash A)=(A \backslash B\cap A \backslash C)\cup(A \backslash B \cap C \backslash A)\cup (B \backslash A\cap A \backslash C) \cup(B \backslash A\cap C \backslash A)$

We use the identity $B\cap (C \backslash A)=(B \cap C) \backslash A =(B \backslash A) \cap C$ (1)

and this identity: $A \backslash B \cap A \backslash C=A \backslash (B \cup C).$

$A \backslash B \cap C \backslash A=(A \backslash B) \backslash A\cap C = \phi$ By (1)

$B \backslash A \cap A \backslash C=(A \backslash C) \backslash A \cap B=\phi$ By (1).

And $B \backslash A \cap C \backslash A=(B \backslash A) \backslash A \cap C=B \backslash A \cap C=(B \cap C ) \backslash A$ by (1)

So $(A\ \bigoplus B\cap A\ \bigoplus C)=(A \backslash (B \cup C))\cup(B \cap C) \backslash A$

And $A \bigoplus(B \cap C)=A \backslash (B \cap C)\cup (B\cap C) \backslash A.$ And $ B \cap C \subseteq B \cup C$ so $A \backslash ( B \cup C) \subseteq A \backslash (B\cap C).$ Hence $(A\ \bigoplus B \cap A\ \bigoplus C)\subseteq A\bigoplus(B\cap C).$